# Why I am getting access denied error on IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, ie7.js

I am having an error related to IE7-js while I do not have IE7-js in my website. I am banging my head around for hours and still did not get a clue about it. [image]

Comment: Maybe you integrate some external 'crap'... ads or so

Comment: Do you have any sort of browser extension or add-on that is meant to emulate other versions of IE?

Comment: I am not sure about it ... url of my site is: http://www.unicaimmobili.com/agenziepartner/ag-immobiliare

Comment: After taking a quick look at the scripts that your site uses I'm growing more confident that you're using an extension or add-on that's causing the issue. Try disabling all of your add-ons and see if you still encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `iframe`s which load content from `http://www.formstack.com/forms/?...`

There's this code on those pages:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This is the script causing `Permission denied` error. The code tries to access `top.window`, which is not allowed when both pages are not in the same domain `(if(/ie7_off/.test(top.location.search)||t<5.5||t>=h.compat)`.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: @user1433900 It's a third party document (?), I'm afraid there's nothing you can do, maybe not load it at all...